# How to extract only two fields using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, networking, tcl

In TCL I am writing the regular expression for below output:

Output args is

```
 packet-filter 0
   identifier      0
   direction       bidirectional
   network-ip      10.7.98.231/32
   ue-port-start   0
   ue-port-end     0
   nw-port-start   0
   nw-port-end     0
   protocol        1
   precedence      0
 packet-filter 1
   identifier      1
   direction       uplink
   network-ip      10.7.98.231/32
   ue-port-start   0
   ue-port-end     0
   nw-port-start   0
   nw-port-end     0
   protocol        1
   precedence      0
```

Output of my Regular Expression : `regexp -all -inline {direction\s+(\S+)} $args` is

```
{direction       bidirectional} bidirectional {direction       uplink} uplink
```

I need to extract the direction value which is `bidirectional` and `uplink`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Your values are in the first capturing group

Comment: Yes, But how to get that value, I also tried below:
% regexp -inline -all {direction\s+(\S+)} $args -out
regexp match variables not allowed when using -inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current case, where the captured substrings are chunks of non-whitespace text, you may re-build the output checking if each item has length set to `1`:

```
set results [regexp -all -inline {direction\s+(\S+)} $args]
set res {}
foreach item $results {
    if {[llength $item] == 1} {
        lappend res $item
    }
}
```

Then, `$res` will  only hold `bidirectional` and `uplink`.

See the [Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/5AON99).

For a more generic case, you may use

```
set res {}
foreach {whole capture1} $results {
   lappend res $capture1
}
```

See [this Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/kalGsq)

You may add more `captureX` arguments to accommodate all the capturing group values returned by your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a loop or something equivalent. If you need to work on each direction individually, a foreach loop is appropriate:

```
set results [regexp -all -inline {direction\s+(\S+)} $args]
foreach {main sub} $results {
    puts $sub
}

# bidirectional
# uplink
```

Or if you need the list of directions, then [`lmap`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/lmap.htm) sounds appropriate:

```
set directions [lmap {main sub} $results {set sub}]
# bidirectional uplink
```

Answer (score 1):

The `regexp` is not absolutely necessary, you may process the value of `args` into a dictionary:

```
set d [dict create]
foreach {k v} $args {
    dict lappend d $k $v
}

puts [dict get $d direction]
```